# Eloquent how I can parse postgresql's hstore?

Tags: php, postgresql, hstore

An eloquent model uses the following table and it is stored in a postgresql database:

```
name: table
id: PK SERIAL
values: HSTORE
```

And the model is named `TableModel`

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class TableModel extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'table';
}
```

But once I retrieve the value `value` I get the following response using tinker session:

```
$model = Model::find('1');
$model->value;
""name"=>"Namae", "value"=>"55""
```

How I can retrieve either the name or the value from the `value` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hstore is simply a format in a form of

```
"key" => "Value","key"=>"value"
```

As seen in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/hstore.html

And easily can be converted into json by replacing the `=>` into `:` and enclosing the string into `{}` a sample code to do this is (continuing the tinker session you mention in your question):

```
$value = $model->value;
$value = str_replace('=>',':',$value);
$value = '{'.$value.'}';
$value = json_decode($value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because hstore format equal to php format you can use PHP `eval` function:

```
$hstore = '"name"=>"Namae", "value"=>"55"';

eval('$d=['.$hstore.'];');

printf("The value is %s \n", $d["value"]);
```

[PHP online fiddle](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/4650cc6d9f326e017e09f58608a6c32a/)

Comment: Usually I'll rather avoid eval because it sometimes may cause code injection and I do not want accidentally the data becoming unwanted code.